# SQL Server Error 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, docker, visual-studio

I have a docker-compose.yml file that creates two containers for phpmyadmin and database.

```
version: '3'
services:
 db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  container_name: db
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
   MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql_db
   MYSQL_USER: piris_sample_user
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: pirisExamplePASS
  ports:
   - "6033:3306"
  volumes:
   - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
 phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  container_name: pma
  links:
   - db
  environment:
   PMA_HOST: db
   PMA_PORT: 3306
   PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
  restart: always
  ports:
   - 8081:80
volumes:
 dbdata:
```

I enabled containers in Docker Compose and got access to phpmyadmin board, and installed MySQL.Data for my Visual Studio WCF project. But when I try to connect my database to project I got error 40, if I put port 6033 or "db" in Server name. I have no such issues with localhost database. What problem it can be?

I tried multiple combinations with server name, like '6033', 'localhost:6033', 'http://localhost:6033', etc. Nothing worked. If I use just 'localhost', Visual Studio sees its databases immediately. I can use phpmyadmin and change databases on 6033 port, but can't connect it to VS project.

Comment: the sever is always `localhost`

Comment: Sql server error indicates that VS is trying to connect to MS SQL Server, which is a different database product. Host name is simply the computer's name, it does not include port number or http.

Comment: Then I don't understand why I can't see "db" in 'localhost' server

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I fixed the problem by MySQL.DataFramework reinstall. I tried to connect by MySQL server, and got an error: "Method is not found: System.String EnvDTE._DTE.getVersion()"